# Hibernate: mapping two properties in the same colums

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

In hibernate is is possible to map the same column with 2 properties of the same class, and have the possibility to reference both in queries?
Is sounds pointless but it would be worth for what I have to do.
In the underying example I could mark the second getter @Transient to keep the second getter, but I would lose the alias in queries, so I would like to keep both "myPropertyAliasOne" and "myPropertyAliasTwo".

```
@Entity
public MyEntity {

   private String myProperty;

   @Column(name="ACTUAL_VALUE")
   public String getMyPropertyAliasOne(){
        return myProperty;
   }

   @Transient
   public String getMyPropertyAliasTwo(){
        return myProperty;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have one column be mapped to two properties, why don't you just map one of them and set the other with the value of the first.

```
@Entity
public MyEntity {

   @Column(name="ACTUAL_VALUE")
   private String myProperty1;
   private String myProperty2;

   public void setMyPropert1(String str){
       myProperty1 = str;
       myProperty2 = str;
   }
   public void setMyPropert2(String str){
       myProperty1 = str;
       myProperty2 = str;
   }
   public void setMyPropert2(){
       myProperty2 = myProperty1;
   }
   @Transient
   public String getMyPropertyAliasOne(){
        return myProperty1;
   }

   public String getMyPropertyAliasTwo(){
        return myProperty2;
   }
}
```

In this case, you manually have these properties always the same. (*but I don't get it, why this redundancy is useful?*)